# Validate specific rule - Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am using latest `Laravel` version.

I have `requests/StoreUser.php`:

```
public function rules() {
    return [
        'name' => 'required||max:255|min:2',
        'email' => 'required|unique:users|email',
        'password' => 'required|max:255|min:6|confirmed'
    ];
}
```

for creating a user.

Now I need and to update the user, but how can I execute only specific rules ?

For the example, if `name` is not provided, but only the `email`, how can I run the validation only for the email ?

Comment: Use the `sometimes` validation rule. But I'm not sure it works with required. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#conditionally-adding-rules

Comment: When you retrieve the rule of arrays, simply remove the key that you don’t want to validate. `array_forget($array, 'key_to_forget');`

Answer (score 2):

This is easier than you thought. Make rules depend on the HTTP method. Here is my working example.

```
public function rules() {
    // rules for updating record
    if ($this->method() == 'PATCH') {
        return [
            'name' => 'nullable||max:255|min:2', // either nullable or remove this line is ok
            'email' => 'required|unique:users|email',
        ];
    } else {
    // rules for creating record
        return [
            'name' => 'required||max:255|min:2',
            'email' => 'required|unique:users|email',
            'password' => 'required|max:255|min:6|confirmed'
        ];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can separate your StoreUser request to CreateUserRequest and UpdateUserRequest to apply different validation rules. I think, this separation makes your code more readable and understandable.

Answer (score 1):

Any HttpValidation request in laravel extends `FormRequest` that extends `Request` so you always have the ability to check request, auth, session, etc ...

So you can inside rules function check request type

```
class AnyRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function rules()
    {
        if ($this->method() == 'PUT'){
            return [

            ]
        }
        if ($this->method() == 'PATH') {
            return [

            ]
        }
    }
}
```

If things get complicated you can create a dedicated new HttpValidation request `PostRequest` `PatchRequest`

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function create(CreateRequest $request)
    {

    }

    public function update(UpdateRequest $request)
    {

    }
}
```

See also the Laravel docs:

- https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation
- https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/FormRequest.html