# i want to know can we make laravel form validation to work just like codeigniter.?

Tags: laravel

i have just moved from codeigniter to laravel and found a problem in laravel in form validation. codeigniter have a file form_validation.php  where we can write all our rules for the application and access them through parameter  can we do it for laravel ?i want to know can we call a set of rules in request file through some parameter so that each time related set will be called for validation.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class FormValidation extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    $rules = array(
        'post'=> array(

             'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
             'body' => 'required',
        ),
        'edit' => array(
            'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
            'body' => 'required',
            'id' => "required"
        )
    )

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            $rules[$parameter]; //parameter which will be post or edit
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55778588/validate-specific-rule-laravel/55781231#55781231

Comment: we can have multiple put or patch requests in same app how can we identify which rules to execute for specific request